# A component required a bean named 'userService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a question on SpringBoot implementation as below.

I am getting error which states:-
Description:

A component required a bean named 'userService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'userService' in your configuration.

Comment: so, how about you "Consider defining a bean named 'userService' in your configuration" ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! I suggest you to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently your question show that you did not do any research effort. Moreover it's totally unclear cause we don't know if you have a bean userService badly implemented, nor if you just not implement this bean, neither what is calling this bean, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use @Service annotation on your service and then spring boot will pick it up, and you should be able to @Autowire in another class/controller. You can also create the bean by using @Bean and returning an instance of the service.

Answer (score 4):

You can define bean using @Component annotation, just add @Component annotation on UserService class. This will initialized UserService as a bean in configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Error : "A component required a bean named 'xyzService' that could not be found.

Resolution : your project would definitely have different package for each classes, so you need to make sure that you configure that in the component scan of the packages in spring boot main class:

**Single package:**

```
@ComponentScan("org.stackoverflow.springboot")
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:conf.properties"})
public class MoviemaxApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```

**multiple packages:**

```
@ComponentScan({"org.stackoverflow.springboot","org.stackoverflow.spring"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootIn10StepsApplication {
```

Answer (score 1):

While the question is rather ambiguous and not properly formed, for those who got the same error, check you have set the following:

1. The @Component, @Service or @Repository annotation set up on your class. Spring searches for the @Component annotation; @Service and @Repository serve as specialization for @Component:

   ```
   package my.project; 
   @Component 
   public class UserService{}
   ```
2. @ComponentScan(...) annotation, or @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ...):

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "my.project")
   public class MyApplicationStarter {}
   ```

@ComponentScan(...) is needed, but it's managed by @SpringBootApplication as well, so there is no need to declare both annotations, use the one that fits your needs. Both @ComponentScan(...) and @SpringBootApplcation(scanBasePackages = ...) allow you to define multiple packages:

- @ComponentScan({"my.project", "my.other.path"})
- @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"my.project", "my.other.path"})

Also, with @SpringBootApplication you can define specifically one or more classes you want to scan:

- @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClass = UserService.class)
- @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClass = {UserService.class, AnotherService.class})